# Why does couchdb config files not work properly?

Tags: couchdb

Can someone explain why doing a `cp default.ini local.ini` would break the couchdb server?  As in, it won't actually listen on the port and there's now way to connect to it anymore?

I'm just trying to understand why this would happen since I am writing automation scripts for couchdb configurations, I just want to know what is going on.  I must obviously be misunderstanding how the config system works.

I thought the default.ini would get read in, set the configs, then the local.ini file would get read in, and overwrite anything that was already configured, and so on...

But instead, it just breaks the whole system to have a local.ini that matches default.ini...

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. default.ini is read first, then local.ini will override anything from default.ini. I suggest that you investigate the problem of having two couchdb instances running at the same time.

However, the local.ini has useful comments and other information so I suggest that you keep a copy of it around. It is not just a duplicate of default.ini.